# Rails 3.2 puts 's' behind generated scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scaffolding

I'm wondering if i can generate a scaffold without getting that annyoing s after all scaffolds.

For example, when I run rails generate scaffold product, rails
generates a scaffold called products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify `config/initializers/inflections.rb` and provide custom [Inflections](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html) for words that you want to pluralize/singularize differently.  Something like:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable "product"
end
```

would make it so `rails g scaffold Product ...` wouldn't pluralize the table name and controller name.

However, I would advise against doing this en masse, or just because you don't like pluralization.  One of Rails strengths is "Convention over Configuration", and like in several cases, if you're not following the convention, it will be more trouble than it's worth in the long run.

Comment: Agree with Nate on this one. The ability to tweak inflections is there to deal with exceptions to the pluralization rules in languages. IMO, it's a misuse to start overriding framework conventions based on personal opinion.  It makes more work for you now, more than likely causes additional trouble in the future, and reduces the "transferability" of your code to other people.  

When I see code that doesn't follow the framework convention, my first reaction is "Ugh, what else did they fiddle with, or monkey-patch?"

Answer (score 1):

May be you should think about changing your `config/initializers/inflections.rb` file. Learn more by links below:

- [Pluralizations and Singularizations (Inflections) in Rails 3](http://blog.thefrontiergroup.com.au/2011/06/pluralizations-and-singularizations-inflections-in-rails-3/)
- [ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html)